# Select content within parenthesis using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to alert the numbers that fall within the parenthesis:

```
var str2 = "This is a string (3444343) with numbers.";
var patt2 = \((.*?)\);
alert(str2.match(patt2));
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryAcid/8nx9v/1/

Comment: Answers are good but I must only alert the numbers. No parenthesis ().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Solution

Based on your original question, this would do:

```
var str2 = "This is a string (3444343) with numbers.";
var patt2 = /\((.*?)\)/;

alert(str2.match(patt2)[1]);
```

An updated jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/S99jd/

For your input string, it alerts `3444343` (without parenthesis).

## Some Explanations

Your snippet needed:

- to add forward-slashes `/` to create the regex,
- to alert by selecting the correct matching group (here, at index `1`, as `match()` returns an array of elements, where element at index`0` is the full match and following indexes correspond to the matching groups).

For a lot more information and help on using regular expressions in JavaScript / ECMAScript, visit: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Answers are good but I must only alert the numbers. No parenthesis ().

Comment: @JusticeGödelConder: Yes, if you run exactly what I gave you, it alerts ONLY the numbers. Try it.

Comment: @JusticeGödelConder: here's a link to a jsfidde with exactly what I wrote above. It alerts numbers only, as you had asked: http://jsfiddle.net/S99jd/

Comment: @JusticeGödelConder: do pay attention to the update to your alert statement as well, in the snippet I give. It's not just the regexp.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose your regular expression literal with forward slashes:

```
var patt2 = /\((.*?)\)/;
```

[Here's the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/8nx9v/2/)

Comment: Answers are good but I must only alert the numbers. No parenthesis ().

Answer (score -1):

As others noted, it's better if you use slashes to create the regex, but if you wish to know how to fix your approach:

```
var patt2 = '(\\(\\d+\\))';
```

or

```
var patt2 = '([(]\\d+[)])';
```

Comment: Answers are good but I must only alert the numbers. No parenthesis ().

Comment: @JusticeGödelConder - Just shift parenthesis outside the capturing ones: '\\((\\d+)\\)' or '[(](\\d+)[)]'